# Наведение мыши с анимацией?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Как сделать при наведении рандомный отступ в радиусе 100px, а также
чтобы при повторном наведении мыши была анимация.

Данный код неадекватно работает:

```js
var box = $('.box');
var randomnumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) - 55;
var randomnumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) - 55;

box.mousemove(function call() {
  box.animate({
      marginTop: randomnumber1 + "px",
      marginLeft: randomnumber2 + "px",
    }, 900,
    function mycallbackAnimate() {
      box.css('margin', '').css('transition', '.3s');
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 100px 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #777;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var box = $('.box');


box.mousemove(start);

function start() {
  box.off();
  let randomnumber1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 250) - 50);
  let randomnumber2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 250) - 50);

  box.animate({
      'margin-top': randomnumber1 + "px",
      'margin-left': randomnumber2 + "px",
    }, 550,
    () => {
      box.animate({
        'margin-top': "100px",
        'margin-left': "80px",
      }, 250);
      box.on('mousemove', start);
    });
};
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 100px 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #777;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:**

```js
var $box = $('.box'), pos1, pos2, s1, s2, box_offset_start = $box.offset(), $chkx = $('#chk-x'), $chky = $('#chk-y');
var vary = [['top','bottom'],['right','left'],['+','-']];
$box.mouseover(function() {

    if( $box.offset().left > 75 ){
        $box.animate({'left' : '-=25'})
    };
    if( $box.offset().top < 25 ){
        $box.animate({'top' : '+=25'})
    };
    if( $box.offset().left < 25 ){
        $box.animate({'left' : '+=25'})
    };
    if( $box.offset().top > 75 ){
        $box.animate({'top' : '-=25'})
    };
    
    pos1 = vary[0][ Math.floor((Math.random() * 2)) ];
    pos2 = vary[1][ Math.floor((Math.random() * 2)) ];
    s1   = vary[2][ Math.floor((Math.random() * 2)) ];
    s2   = vary[2][ Math.floor((Math.random() * 2)) ];
    
    $(this).animate({
    [pos1] : [s1] + '=50',
      [pos2] : [s2] + '=50'
    }, 600, function(){
      $(this).animate({
        'top' : box_offset_start.top/2 + $box.height()/2,
        'left': box_offset_start.left/2 + $box.width()/2
      },'ease-out')
    });
});
```

```css
.papa-box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50px;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
.box {
 width:25px;
 height:25px;
  border-radius:20px;
 background-color:#777;
 border:1px solid #999;
  position:absolute;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="papa-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: Хорошо, только надо чтобы потом на место стал блок) И немного не так. Суть - я навожу, от отталкивается плавно а потом плавно на место стал и главное с отступом рандомный но не больше 100px